# azure Notification Hub in MAUI

Tags: .net, maui, azure-notificationhub, .net-7.0

How to implement azure notification hub in MAUI?

I tried following the xamarin([link](https://learn.microsoft.com/pt-br/azure/notification-hubs/xamarin-notification-hubs-push-notifications-android-gcm)) walkthrough but the packages are not accepted and it shows the error

```
Unexpected failure of task "VerifyVersionsTask"
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

**1) in [microsoft tutorial](https://learn.microsoft.com/pt-br/azure/notification-hubs/xamarin-notification-hubs-push-notifications-android-gcm) install only**

```
Xamarin.Azure.NotificationHubs.Android
```

**2) in MainActivty.cs example**

```
public class MainActivity : MauiAppCompatActivity
{
    const string CONNECTION_STRING = "Endpo";
    const string HUB_NAME = "n";
    protected override void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        FirebaseApp.InitializeApp(this);
        base.OnCreate(savedInstanceState);
        // Listen for push notifications
        WindowsAzure.Messaging.NotificationHubs.NotificationHub.SetListener(new NotificationListener());

        // Start the SDK
        WindowsAzure.Messaging.NotificationHubs.NotificationHub.Start(this.Application, HUB_NAME, CONNECTION_STRING);
        HandleIntent(Intent);
        CreateNotificationChannelIfNeeded();
    }

    protected override void OnNewIntent(Intent intent)
    {
        base.OnNewIntent(intent);
        HandleIntent(intent);
    }

    private static void HandleIntent(Intent intent)
    {
        FirebaseCloudMessagingImplementation.OnNewIntent(intent);
    }

    private void CreateNotificationChannelIfNeeded()
    {
        if (Build.VERSION.SdkInt >= BuildVersionCodes.O)
        {
            CreateNotificationChannel();
        }
    }

    private void CreateNotificationChannel()
    {
        var channelId = $"{PackageName}.general";
        var notificationManager = (NotificationManager)GetSystemService(NotificationService);
        var channel = new NotificationChannel(channelId, "General", NotificationImportance.Default);
        notificationManager.CreateNotificationChannel(channel);
        FirebaseCloudMessagingImplementation.ChannelId = channelId;
        //FirebaseCloudMessagingImplementation.SmallIconRef = Resource.Drawable.ic_push_small;
    }
}

public partial class NotificationListener : Java.Lang.Object, INotificationListener
{
    void INotificationListener.OnPushNotificationReceived(Context context, INotificationMessage message)
    {
        //Push Notification arrived - print out the keys/values
        var data = message.Data;
        if (data != null)
        {
            foreach (var entity in data)
            {
                Android.Util.Log.Debug("AZURE-NOTIFICATION-HUBS", "Key: {0}, Value: {1}", entity.Key, entity.Value);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you tested this? Can you confirm that `Xamarin.Azure.NotificationHubs.Android` works with .Net Maui?

Comment: @FerramenteiroSteve 
Yes it works, 
you can install Plugin.Firebase

Comment: @RafaelParenza can you please share the full set up here, I'm stuck on the maui azure pushnotification part for a long.

Comment: @Suácia follow the step by step of the microsoft documentation and in the installation install only Xamarin.Azure.NotificationHubs.Android and Plugin.firebase.
You can post your problem in a question and send me the link

Comment: I was also unable to to follow the tutorial but set up my own working example here https://github.com/Xcelerator-Group/dotnet-maui-notifications if anyone wants to check it out.