# Maui push notification

Tags: c#, ios, maui

How can i use push notification with azure notification hub in maui ? Anyone having some idea how can i work on it?

Is there any link available for that ??

I have tried with this package : Microsoft.Azure.NotificationHubs

Here is my app delegate:

```
public override bool FinishedLaunching(UIApplication application, NSDictionary launchOptions)
{
    try
    {
        ObjCRuntime.Class.ThrowOnInitFailure = false;

        #region screen height & width
        App.screenWidth = (int)UIScreen.MainScreen.Bounds.Width;
        App.screenHeight = (int)UIScreen.MainScreen.Bounds.Height;
        #endregion

        // Request permission to display notifications
        UNUserNotificationCenter.Current.RequestAuthorization(
            UNAuthorizationOptions.Alert | UNAuthorizationOptions.Sound | UNAuthorizationOptions.Badge,
            (granted, error) =>
            {
                if (error != null)
                {
                    // Handle the error, if any
                    Console.WriteLine($"Error requesting notification permissions: {error}");
                    return;
                }

                if (granted)
                {
                    // Permission granted, register for remote notifications on the UI thread
                    InvokeOnMainThread(RegisterForRemoteNotifications);
                }
                else
                {
                    // Permission denied
                    Console.WriteLine("Notification permissions denied by the user.");
                }
            });

        return base.FinishedLaunching(application, launchOptions);
    }


    catch (Exception ex)
    {

        Console.WriteLine("Shweta=======" + ex.Message);
        return true;
    }

}

private void RegisterForRemoteNotifications()
{
    UIApplication.SharedApplication.RegisterForRemoteNotifications();
}

[Export("application:didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken:")]
public void RegisteredForRemoteNotifications(UIApplication application, NSData deviceToken)
{
    var deviceTokenString = BitConverter.ToString(deviceToken.ToArray()).Replace("-", "").ToLower();

    // Register the device token with Azure Notification Hubs
    RegisterWithNotificationHubs(deviceTokenString);


}


private async void RegisterWithNotificationHubs(string deviceTokenString)
{
    try
    {
        var services = new ServiceCollection();

        // Register the notification hub client
        services.AddSingleton<NotificationHubClient>(provider =>
        {
            // var configuration = provider.GetRequiredService<IConfiguration>();
            var connectionString = ConfigPush.ListenConnectionString;
            var hubName = ConfigPush.NotificationHubName;

            return NotificationHubClient.CreateClientFromConnectionString(connectionString, hubName);
        });

        var serviceProvider = services.BuildServiceProvider();
        var notificationHubClient = serviceProvider.GetRequiredService<NotificationHubClient>();

        var registrationId = Guid.NewGuid().ToString();

        // Create the registration
        var registration = new AppleRegistrationDescription(deviceTokenString)
        {
            RegistrationId = registrationId,
            Tags = new HashSet<string> { "default" } // Set your desired tags
        };

        // Create a new registration


        // Register the device with the notification hub
        var registrationDescription = await notificationHubClient.CreateOrUpdateRegistrationAsync(registration);
        Console.WriteLine($"Registration ID: {registrationDescription.RegistrationId}");
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {

    }
   

}
```

when i'm trying to register with notification hub, i'm getting this exception:

Microsoft.Azure.NotificationHubs.Messaging.BadRequestException:  RegistrationId fa02653e-71d9-4afe-bbc6-6995107757b0 is malformed.TrackingId:63ff1730-c6b2-4cce-8c48-ecc1b11ba498,TimeStamp:6/14/2023 8:43:51 PM +00:00
at Microsoft.Azure.NotificationHubs.NotificationHubClient.SendRequestAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, String trackingId, HttpStatusCode[] successfulResponseStatuses, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
at Microsoft.Azure.NotificationHubs.NotificationHubClient.<>c__DisplayClass195_0`1.<b__0>d[[Microsoft.Azure.NotificationHubs.AppleRegistrationDescription, Microsoft.Azure.NotificationHubs, Version=4.1.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35]].MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location ---

can someone please here ?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Did you look into https://github.com/Azure/azure-notificationhubs & samples in readme?

Comment: for MAUI https://github.com/Azure/azure-notificationhubs-dotnet

Comment: @Blu ... but Microsoft.Azure.NotificationHubs is for the back-end.
We need Xamarin.Azure.NotificationHubs.iOS to register the token to Azure NotificationHubs

Comment: if you tried something and couldn't make it work, post the relevant details of what you did and what specific problems you encountered.  Your question as written is off-topic

Comment: @Jason I used mentioned plugin, but in iOS, i'm not getting any notification and devicetoken also null

Comment: You need to provide **details**.  Please read [ask] for guidance.

Comment: @Jason I've updated details

Comment: Maybe https://stackoverflow.com/a/76325793/199364

Comment: I'm looking for iOS. your suggested link have android only. @ToolmakerSteve

Comment: I've added `ios` tag to the question, to make that clearer.